# Reading data from a COM port using the WAKE-8 protocol using Python

Tags: python, serial-port, port, protocols

There is a device that is physically connected to a computer via RS-232 or USB. At the logical level, the device communicates with the PC using the WAKE-8 protocol. What Python library can be used to read data from the device? Is there any more or less ready and simple solution?